# PDOException : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 7890 Can't find file

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, xampp

I am trying to run the following project

```
https://github.com/saeedvaziry/laravel-vue-polling-app.git'
```

i am following the project readme.md but i am getting a PDOException when i run

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --seed
```

My Question what is causing this error and how can i resolve it

Here is the cli output

```
 PDOException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 7890 Can't find file 'C:UsersuserDesktoplaravel-vue-polling-appstorageips.csv'.

  at C:\Users\user\Desktop\laravel-vue-polling-app\database\seeds\IpAddressesTableSeeder.php:18
    14|         $ipsPath = storage_path('ips.csv');
    15|         $pdo = \DB::connection()->getPdo();
    16|         $pdo->exec("
    17|                         LOAD DATA LOCAL
  > 18|                                 INFILE '" . $ipsPath . "'
    19|                         INTO TABLE
    20|                                 `ip_addresses`
    21|                         FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    22|                         ENCLOSED BY '\"'

  Exception trace:

  1   PDO::exec("
                        LOAD DATA LOCAL
                                INFILE 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\laravel-vue-polling-app\storage\ips.csv'
                        INTO TABLE
                                `ip_addresses`
                        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
                        ENCLOSED BY '"'
                        LINES TERMINATED BY '
'
                        IGNORE 0 LINES;
        ")
      C:\Users\user\Desktop\laravel-vue-polling-app\database\seeds\IpAddressesTableSeeder.php:18

  2   IpAddressesTableSeeder::run()
      C:\Users\user\Desktop\laravel-vue-polling-app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:29
```

and here is the seeder file

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class IpAddressesTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $ipsPath = storage_path('ips.csv');
        $pdo = \DB::connection()->getPdo();
        $pdo->exec("
            LOAD DATA LOCAL
                INFILE '" . $ipsPath . "'
            INTO TABLE
                `ip_addresses`
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
            ENCLOSED BY '\"'
            LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
            IGNORE 0 LINES;
        ");
    }
}
```

None of the files have been altered by me and is as is in the repo as far as i know

Answer (score 3):

Windows uses `\` for the path separator, which is also the escape character in MySQL. When you pass `C:\Users\user\Desktop\laravel-vue-polling-app\storage\ips.csv` to MySQL, it thinks the single `\` is the escape character, not the path separator. To fix this, do

```
$ipsPath = addslashes($ipsPath);
```

before you use it in your query.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see

PDOException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 7890 Can't find file '**C:UsersuserDesktoplaravel-vue-polling-appstorageips.csv**'. 
no directory separators ?

did you try to use `[ESCAPED BY 'char']`

Your seeder file $ips should be like

```php
$ipsPath = addslashes(storage_path('ips.csv'));
...
....
```